# Unwrapping Optional String To Int & Making it non-optional

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

It has been a long time since I have coded in iOS and I am upgrading the old app to swift 3. I am really struggling with one issue of using optional variables.

I have a textfield which is optional. I want it unwrapped into a non-optional **Int** so that I can use it in the other functions for calculation.

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtRuns: UITextField!

func sendScore()
{   
    let runs        = txtRuns.text!
    let overs       = txtOvers.text!
    let balls       = txtBalls.text!
    let wkts        = txtWkts.text!
    let target      = txtTarget.text!
    let totalOvers  = txtTotalOvers.text!

    let strData  = "S|R\(runs)" + getOptionalScoreData(
             runs: Int(runs),
             wkts: Int(wkts),
             overs: Int(overs),
             balls: Int(balls),
             target: Int(target),
             totalOvers: Int(totalOvers)
             )
}

func getOptionalScoreData(runs: Int, wkts: Int, overs: Int, balls: Int, target: Int, totalOvers: Int) -> String
{
    if ( runs == 0 ) {
        return  getCurrentRunRate(runs: runs)
    }

    return "";
}
```

As you can see, I have so many functions to call and I want this textfield to turn into non-optional INT.

Now I have tried several options that I read over here but the error messages only change. The problem didn't solve.

Current ERROR is

```
 The value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Please help.
Thanks

.................

Please note that I don't think nested check is a nice idea here because all these variables are independent of each other. One can be nil but other can be still passed and used.

If I nest checks like this, it means that no other value will be passed if runs are nil.

```
if let runs = txtRuns.text, let runsInInt = Int(runs) {
    if let overs = txtOvers.text, let oversInInt = Int(overs) {
        if let wkts = txtWkts.text, let wktsInInt = Int(wkts) {

            strData = "S|R\(runs)\(overs)\(wkts)" + getOptionalScoreData( runs: runsInInt, overs: oversInInt, wkts: wktsInInt)

}
```

Comment: try             if let txt = txtRuns?.text{ // Do some functions using the above value}

Comment: @Bikram this is the error if I use textRun?.text `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: @Sallu, Try to add a private extension on `UITextField` to get `int` from text. Then you can directly use `txtRuns.intText` etc..

Comment: @Sallu, I have posted the comment as answer. I think you are looking for this from what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are frequently getting value from `UITextField` as `Int`, you can add an extension as follows:

```
extension UITextField {
    var intValue: Int {
        get {
            if let text = self.text {
                return Int(text) ?? 0
            }
            return 0
        }
        set {
            self.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

You can add the above as private extension in your viewcontroller too. Now you can rewrite your code as:

```
func sendScore() {
    let strData  = "S|R\(txtRuns.intValue)\(overs.intValue)\(wkts.intValue)" + getOptionalScoreData(
        runs: txtRuns.intValue,
        wkts: wkts.intValue,
        overs: overs.intValue,
        balls: balls.intValue,
        target: target.intValue,
        totalOvers: totalOvers.intValue)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user1000, your answer was good too. I see that you deleted it. But he was asking for this I guess since he is repeating it many times.

Comment: This answer was just too good @user1000. I was just thinking why it didnt come to my mind :-D. Thanks. Great help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Sallu, No problem. Good to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

`Int(runs)` call constructor of Int following:

`public init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)`

Because `String` to `Int` might failed due to the String might not a valid integer.

How would you deal with it?

You can reference  Sallu's comment.

1. user `!` to guarantee the `String` in `UITextField` is absolute a valid integer, or app crash.

`runs: Int(runs)!`

2. user `??` to give a default value if the `String` in `UITextField` is not a valid integer.

`runs: Int(runs) ?? 0`

In the case the default value is 0